1960s comedy/love film about a single woman who finds out she's pregnant and refuses her suitors
This movie is a comedy/love film from the 1960s, about a single, possibly divorced, woman who finds out she's pregnant.  Three men want to marry her when they find out, but she refuses.  
When she goes to the hospital, the real father shows up and they get married before the baby is born.  
The film is certainly not a classic. I want to say it stars Doris Day, Tony Randall and Rock Hudson, but none of their movies seem to have this story line.
